# hide a search bar after adding element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to hide an search bar in jquery after changing his class 
My problem is when I click on the element to hide the search bar nothing happend
I try to add this :

```
$('#menu_bas').on('click', ".fa-times", function () {
    $('.c_hover').css('display', 'initial');
    $('#wrapper-category').css('text-align', 'middle');
    $('#search_input').css('display', 'none');
    $('.fa-times').addClass('fa-search');
    $('.fa-times').removeClass('fa-times');

});
```

Here is my jsfiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsqgxpn/5/

Comment: You should read about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)  - https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsqgxpn/13/

Comment: @AlonEitan that was I did

Comment: Please check my edited comment with a link to a working fiddle

Comment: Great! Please accept @GabyAkaGPetrioli's answer because it's a good and correct answer (Click on the green V icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the delegation for both cases since you apply it to the same element, but want to differentiate based on the current class.

Otherwise the `.fa-search` click handler would run in both clicks and mess thigs up

```
      $('#menu_bas')
        .on('click', '.fa-search', function() {
          $('.c_hover').css('display', 'none');
          $('#wrapper-category').css('text-align', 'right');
          $('#search_input').css('display', 'inline-block');
          $('.fa-search').addClass('fa-times');
          $('.fa-search').removeClass('fa-search');
        })
        .on('click', ".fa-times", function() {
          $('.c_hover').css('display', '');
          $('#wrapper-category').css('text-align', '');
          $('#search_input').css('display', 'none');
          $('.fa-times').addClass('fa-search');
          $('.fa-times').removeClass('fa-times');
        });
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsqgxpn/24/

---

It would be better, though, to just toggle a class to the `#menu_bas` element, and handle all changes through CSS

Like this

```
$('#menu_bas')
    .on('click', '.fa-search, .fa-times', function() {
      $('#menu_bas').toggleClass('search-active');
      $(this).toggleClass('fa-times fa-search');
});
```

and

```
.search-active .c_hover {display: none}
.search-active #wrapper-category {text-align: right}
.search-active .search_input {display: inline-block;}
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsqgxpn/29/